# Querying against an array only works for first element

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having an issue searching for items within an array in a document; a simple tagging system in my case. I have a relatively simple document representing a recipe. This is a truncated version of the data in the index:

```
{
   "_index" : "recipes",
  "_type" : "recipe",
  "_id" : "37",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "id" : 37,
    "title" : "Crab Cakes",
    "tags" : [
      "seafood",
      "appetizer"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I search for the tag `seafood` it matches this recipe. However, when I search for the tag `appetizer`, I get nothing. Here is the explain for a very basic appetizer query:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/recipes/recipe/37/_explain?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query":{"term":{"tags":"appetizer"}}}'`

Which results in this:

```
{
  "_index" : "recipes",
  "_type" : "recipe",
  "_id" : "37",
  "matched" : false,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.0,
    "description" : "no matching term",
    "details" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your mapping?

Comment: There are no specific mappings for `tags`, it is just the dynamic mappings. Which I could expect to be the issue. Here is what shows up automatically:

"tags" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "english"
          }

Comment: Change the term query to a match query since tags is an analyzed field or change mapping to a keyword field for exact matches using term queries

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer came in comments from [sramalingam24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3708175/sramalingam24). It was to change the query to a `match` instead of a `term`.

[updated]

I also tested switching the `tags` to be a `keyword` field and that works as well. This is the solution I ended up going with.